# Disable php functions via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to disable few php functions only in a specific folder, I thought of using htaccess:

For example I have tried adding this line:

php_admin_value disable_functions "system, etc.."

However it doesn't work, I just get 500 error, if you know how to make it work, please share.

Appreciate any help on this subject.

-- EDIT --

I have turned on my litespeed and now there are no more errors, but system() is still allowed, I want to turn it off for my server's home folder.

Any solutions ?

Comment: Check your server's error log. Details about the 500 will be listed there. most likely you've got a syntax error in the .htaccess file, which can also involve things like using a directive which the server config does not allow.

Comment: I think it's about your syntax, check error log as Marc B said

Comment: I got this error:   "..../public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"   - I have also tried "php_value" but the same error occurs, do you know the correct command for this ?

Answer (score 3):

`php_admin_value` is not valid in `.htaccess` files. It can only be used in `httpd.conf`. See: http://php.net/configuration.changes for details.

Use `php_value` instead, or add the directive in a `<Location>` or `<Directory>` block in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: so should I use "php_value system off" etc each command separately, would this work ?

Comment: `php_value disable_functions "system"` or something of the sort.

Comment: Well, it simply can't be done in .htaccess. The other suggestions are fine.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

> This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security
>   reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of function names.
>   disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode.
>
> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
>   User-defined functions are unaffected.
>
> **This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf.**

Answer (score 0):

Propably the HTTP Status code 500 comes from wrong .htaccess file.

You can rename the .htaccess file to something else for a while to check if the problem comes from there. If so you can then paste the .htaccess code here to give you the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

in your .htaccess put

php_admin_value disable_functions " "

This is only if you are allow to do so. Give it a shot.

Comment: this is wrong. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions