# Disable php functions within htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

I'm trying to create a private clone of a popular website which gives the possibility to "write php code online" as a personal exercise.

- I write some code in a text area
- code is executed some way server side
- output is returned

I want the output to be exactly as it would be if served by an apache instance, with all the errors and warning my code generated.

There's an existing framework which serves the site webpages (a front controller, an orm and so on) so I CANT USE DISABLE FUNCTIONS IN PHP INI. Or everything wouldn't be usable at all.

I tried to save the input in a file and then run it with an exec like the following:

```
exec("php -c mycustomphpinifile input.php 2>&1 > output.txt");
```

But the errors outputted won't be the same as the apache ones.

The final solution I'm trying to adopt is to use the php_value or php_admin_value within the httpd.conf or the .htaccess in order to disable a whole list (as you can imagine) of dangerous functions.

However...

```
php_value disable_functions "my,functions,comma,separated"
```

doesn't work with such a big list as it seems.
I have to disable something like 2k functions: is there any buffer size trouble with the php_value within the htaccess? Anyone can guess a solution to this problem?

Comment: i'm not sure on the desired outcome here, if you disable them, what happens when one of them is called in your application?

Comment: You have to disable 2,000 functions?!?! Why are you doing that? Might be smarter to just not include any of those function files or just delete your whole PHP application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions), you can't use the `disable_functions` setting anywhere other than in a `php.ini` file, so I'm very surprised this is working at all.

If you need per-vhost or per-directory restrictions on functions, I would suggest using separate instances of [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/), each of which can have its own `php.ini`. It also provides additional security benefits, such as complete sandboxing per daemon instance.

Comment: Well, using different php.ini files was my first shot. Then I found that PHPIniDir directive can be set just once since is a global directive. If switching to PHP-FPM allows me to use differents php.ini files than I guess that it's a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

That can’t be done in an `.htaccess`.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810975/disable-php-functions-via-htaccess).

But it does seem it can be done this way. Refer to the section that states 'in .htaccess in your public_html add the following:' [here](http://wiki.elxis.org/wiki/PHP_settings):

```
php_flag short_open_tag Off
php_flag register_globals Off
php_flag display_errors Off
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_value date.timezone "Europe/Athens"
php_value session.save_path "/absolute/path/to/writable/folder/one_level_up_of/public_html"
```

Note where it states:

> php_value disable_functions "system, exec, passthru, shell_exec,
>   suexec, dbmopen, popen, proc_open, disk_free_space, diskfreespace,
>   set_time_limit, leak"

And the footnote regarding that:

> these settings can only be changed through default php.ini file, if
>   there are not configured as needed and you haven't access to php.ini
>   contact to your hosting provider to set them for you!

**EDIT:**
Also, do you have access the actual Apache2 virtual host configs? If so then you might want to research how to use `suhosin.executor.func.blacklist` instead; [see this page](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=623944). Seems like that is a nicer way to have PHP functions disabled on a per host/domain basis. Perhaps even per `<Directory>` or `<Location>`?

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerAlias www.test.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
DocumentRoot /home/test/public_html

php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "passthru, show_source, shell_exec, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_terminate, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, escapeshellcmd, escapeshellarg"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think you overlooked the part where the OP says `However if I write just four or five functions it works, but I have to disable something like 2k functions` It is indeed working already, but does not work when OP puts a lot of functions in the list.

Comment: Then it works but only with few functions?? This indeed su**s: I run two Virtual Hosts and I need to disallow a lot of php functions within one of it. I guess there's no solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `php_admin_value` instead of `php_value` in your `vhost.conf` file or in your `.htaccess` file

```
<Directory /your/application/dir>
    AllowOverride None
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors off
    php_value error_reporting 3
    php_value memory_limit 128M
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/your/application/dir/imagecache"
    php_value max_execution_time 10
    php_admin_value disable_functions "exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source"
</Directory>
```

Comment: Even though phpinfo shows disable_functions updated in the local info this doesn't actually disable the listed php functions unfortunately. 
<?php echo `whoami 2>&1`; ?>
<?php echo shell_exec('whoami 2>&1'); ?>