# can i disable php function for specific directory?

Tags: php, function, security

i want to disable some function for data.php (../home/file/data.php) directory file?
it is possible?

can is used php.in in this directory?

STEP: 1 Open php.ini file:  ../home/file/php.ini

STEP: 2 Find disable_functions and set new list as follows: disable_functions= exec,passthru,shell_exec,system

STEP: 3 service httpd restart

With the help of above steps I am able to disable all the above functions. Now these functions are no longer available on server.

If I want to enable or disable these functions for particular directories then it is possible or not?

Comment: yes and no... u can disable this function via php.ini, but you need to create separete instances of worker. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532987/disable-php-functions-within-htaccess

Comment: I think that php ini sets can be changed with .htaccess (assuming your webserver is Apache)