# PHP doesn't deny disabled_functions

Tags: php, apache

Along to `phpinfo()` the following is prohibited:

```
apache_child_terminate,apache_get_modules,apache_get_version,apache_getenv,apache_note,apache_setenv,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,define_syslog_variables,disk_free_space,diskfreespace,dl,error_log,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,ftp_connect,ftp_exec,ftp_get,ftp_login,ftp_nb_fput,ftp_put,ftp_raw,ftp_rawlist,ini_alter,ini_get_all,ini_restore,link,mysql_pconnect,openlog,passthru,pfsockopen,php_uname,phpinfo,popen,posix_getpwuid,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_uname,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,set_time_limit,shell_exec,symlink,syslog,system,tmpfile,virtual
```

But phpinfo still works, I have created a file written `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it. But along to phpinfo it should be disabled, but it still echoes!

I have prohibited it using `php_admin_value disable_functions "apache_child_terminate,apache_get_modules,apache_get_version,apache_getenv,apache_note,apache_setenv,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,define_syslog_variables,disk_free_space,diskfreespace,dl,error_log,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,ftp_connect,ftp_exec,ftp_get,ftp_login,ftp_nb_fput,ftp_put,ftp_raw,ftp_rawlist,ini_alter,ini_get_all,ini_restore,link,mysql_pconnect,openlog,passthru,pfsockopen,php_uname,phpinfo,popen,posix_getpwuid,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_uname,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,set_time_limit,shell_exec,symlink,syslog,system,tmpfile,virtual"` in the vhost conf.

What am I doing wrong? What have I missed?

Comment: You mean `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?

Comment: Can you show how/where phpinfo() tells you that those functions are banned?

Comment: there is a row called disable_functions with the content i wrote above

Comment: phpinfo() values have two columns. Which one is this in?

Comment: in the right

|disable_functions|apache_child....|

Comment: Are you sure that line is talking about disabled functions? Does it say so in the column to the left? My bet is it didn't understand the setting, and what you are seeing is simply a list of the things you tried to pass through .htaccess.

Comment: ahhh possible duplicate of [Disable php functions via .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810975/disable-php-functions-via-htaccess)

Comment: I did it in the httpd.conf. On the left row is standing disable_function and on the right column the list with the modules.

Comment: But the link says this can be done in php.ini only, not in the Apache config

Comment: there is not standing disabled_function, so that's only the values passed, but they were not processed.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my guess.

Comment: I now tried it using suhosin.executor.func.blacklist, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried php.ini?

Comment: I tried it, no success, even after it directly to the suhosin file in conf.d folder. Simply no blocking

Comment: Suhosin may require a web server restart, I don't know (oh and php.ini the same)