# is possible disable functions only for directory in PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I know disabled_functions only settings from php.ini,
But I want to disable some functions only for directory or virtual hosting,
How can I do this?

Comment: Use an `.htaccess` file. There's tons of info around about it.

Comment: You can't — `disable_functions` can only be applied globally. See [Disable php functions via .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810975/disable-php-functions-via-htaccess) (duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you can use .htaccess file or use ini_set() php mehtod for specific file or make a general file with the options using this mehtod and include it in the required files.

Answer (score 0):

the php documentation gives you all the answers that you need. you can't disable functions in `.htaccess` files.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

---

**disable_functions** string

> This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security
>   reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of function names.
>   disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode.
>
> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
>   User-defined functions are unaffected.
>
> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this
>   in httpd.conf.